# How to generate a list of natural numbers from 1....n?

Tags: list, function, haskell, functional-programming

I am currently trying to, inside my function, generate a list. The user will pass in one parameter, which will be an `Int`. The function's job is to generate a list, starting from `1`, and going up to `n`. So the list would look something like

```
[1....n]
```

What I have done thus far is this:

```
iterate (+1) 1
```

While this provides the correct pattern, it goes on forever. How would I be able to stop at `n`? In addition, how would I be able to append `'1'` at the end of the list, as such:

```
[1...n,1]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `[1..n]`? It's a perfectly valid expression which you can output from a function (for example). As for putting a `1` at the end, that's just `[1..n] ++ [1]`

Comment: You could also `take n (iterate (+1) 1)` to get a finite sublist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's literally as simple as:

```
f :: Int -> [Int]
f n = [1..n] ++ [1]
```